# get dictionary enumerate as list

Tags: python

I tried to get result of the enumerate as list.

I tried as follows

```
D = {'red': '#FF0000',
 'lime': '#00FF00',
 'blue': '#0000FF'}

print (D)

for key, value in D.items():
    print (key, value)

print (list(D.keys()))
print (list(enumerate(D.keys())))

{'red': '#FF0000', 'lime': '#00FF00', 'blue': '#0000FF'}
red #FF0000
lime #00FF00
blue #0000FF
['red', 'lime', 'blue']
[(0, 'red'), (1, 'lime'), (2, 'blue')]
```

The result should be :

```
[0,1,2].
```

#### How to get [0,1,2] from D?

Comment: `range(len(D))`?

Comment: I'd be interested to seeing a comparison in speed between range and enumerate in this case.

Comment: @BramVanroy `enumerate` will actually iterate the dictionary while `range(len)` will only check the size of the dictionary. That’s fundamentally different and range will certainly be much faster if you just want to count from `0` to the length of the dictionary.

Comment: @poke True but Len first has to calculate the length, then the range has to be created and then listifies, whereas enumerate does it all in one go. So I'm curious how big the difference is.

Comment: @BramVanroy The length is stored for Python collections. So it is always constant. And `range` objects are super efficient since they don’t actually contain all those elements within. And `enumerate()` and `range()` both create generators, so you will have to “listify” both results anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate gives you tuples as `(index, value)` so you would new to unpack those:

```
enumeration = [i for i, k in enumerate(D.keys())]
```

---

For interest, `range` is faster:

```py
from timeit import timeit

D = {'red': '#FF0000', 'lime': '#00FF00', 'blue': '#0000FF'}

def e(d=D):
    return [i for i, _ in enumerate(d.keys())]

def r(d=D):
    return list(range(len(d)))

def e_gen(d=D):
    return (i for i, _ in enumerate(d.keys()))

def r_gen(d=D):
    return range(len(d))

methods = [r, e, r_gen, e_gen]
for m in methods:
    print("{}\t{:.10f}s".format(m, timeit(m, number=100) / 100))

# <function r at 0x105715488>       0.0000010044s
# <function e at 0x10551d1e0>       0.0000013061s
# <function r_gen at 0x1059f7ae8>   0.0000006587s
# <function e_gen at 0x105678488>   0.0000014094s
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mad Physicist's comment:

```py
print([x for x in range(len(D))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get `[0, 1, 2]`, then you can just use the `range` over the length of the dictionary:

```
>>> list(range(len(D)))
[0, 1, 2]
```

Note that those indexes will not help you at all when you are trying to access the dictionary. Dictionary entries are always pairs of keys and values, and you will have to use an actual key to access the value in the dictionary.

That’s why when you iterate over the dictionary, you are essentially iterating over its keys:

```
>>> for key in D:
        print(key, D[key])

red #FF0000
lime #00FF00
blue #0000FF
```

Alternatively, you can also iterate over the *items* of the dictionary which will give you the key and its value at the same time:

```
>>> for (key, value) in D.items():
        print(key, value)

red #FF0000
lime #00FF00
blue #0000FF
```